# From Winxp to Win7 Need to reinstall all the Rails gems?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, aptana

I've switched from a winxp box to a new win7 64bit box and i want to get my rails development project running on it. i can copy my project folder to the new box and now i want to migrate all the gems that i used on my winxp to the win7.

1. do i need to "gem install" all the gems again on the win7? or i can hv an easier way to do it? pls give details on how to do it.
2. i want to migrate my schema.rb to the newly installed mysql on the win7. how to do it? i installed aptana studio 3 but the rake and generator functions are no longer available.

thanks
batterhead

Answer (score 0):

1) Do you have Gemfile?  If so, just run `bundle update` command at your project's directory.

2) Run `rake db:migrate` at your project's directory (assuming you already updated a configuration file)

HTH